# HTTP post to create InfluxDB database with libcurl

Tags: c++, http-post, libcurl, influxdb

I'm trying to make an http post with libcurl library to create an InfluxDB database, as indicated in their website:

`curl -i -XPOST http://localhost:8086/query --data-urlencode "q=CREATE DATABASE mydb"`

It looks like my code is not working. It doesnt give me any errors but db is not created. But instead if i try to add some points to an existing database, with the same function, it works. I think i miss the correct way of adding "q=CREATE DATABASE mydb" part. How should i change my code?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

       char *url = "http://localhost:8086/query";
       char *data = "q=CREATE DATABASE mydb";
       /* should i change data string to json? 
          data = "{\"q\":\"CREATE DATABASE mydb\" }" */

       bool res = createInfluxDB(url, data);

       /*control result*/ 

       return(0);
}

bool createInfluxDB(char *url, char *data) {
      CURL *curl;

      curl = curl_easy_init();

      if(curl) {
        CURLcode res;
        /* What Content-type should i use?*/
        struct curl_slist* headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
        /*--data-urlencode*/
        char *urlencoded = curl_easy_escape(curl, data, int(strlen(data)));

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencoded);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long)strlen(urlencoded));

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /*omitted controls*/

        curl_free(urlencoded);
        curl_slist_free_all(headers);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
      }

      return(true);
    }
```

Comment: Did you check your influDB user permissions ? maybe your call is ok, but the DB block the action.

Comment: @Yann but then it would refuse the connection and would return false, no? As i said, i can add data to an existing database in the same way.

Comment: Hey @user did the "mydb" database doesn't already exist ?

Comment: @Yann nope, i tried also with other names, doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

After analyzing packets with http post request (which was returning Bad Request) i arrived to the point that i shouldn't add query parameters as data. But instead it should be part of url. So after changing code like that, it works!

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   char *url = "http://localhost:8086/query?q=CREATE+DATABASE+mydb";
   bool res = createInfluxDB(url);

   /*control result*/ 

   return(0);
}

bool createInfluxDB(char *url) {
  CURL *curl;

  curl = curl_easy_init();

  if(curl) {
    CURLcode res;
    struct curl_slist* headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /*omitted controls*/

    curl_slist_free_all(headers);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }

  return(true);
}
```

Comment: Ok fine, wp :) think to accept your answer in order to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED ANSWER**:

You still got a missnamed var in a if statment:

```
if (urlencode) free(...
```

That should be

```
if (urlencoded) free(...
```

Then in your headers you set the application type as json and I don't think that's what you want.
Something like "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" may be better.

```
struct curl_slist* headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

**ORIGNIAL ANSWER**:

A workaround could be in your

```
char *data = curl_easy_escape(curl, json, int(strlen(json)));
```

That **overload** *data* with a *json* var that doesn't exist ?

Something like this may work better:

```
data = curl_easy_escape(curl, data, int(strlen(data)));
```

Comment: thanks, it was an error i made while copying code here... anyway i checked again as you coded but still doesn't work.

Comment: @user3717434 I edited my answer with the code changes you did.

Comment: i think you're right about using "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" but it still doesn't work. I also tried to change data to "q=CREATE+DATABASE+mydb" but no way working.